# How to shorten this query?

Tags: mysql, sql

## How to shorten this query?

### I want to change This part of query, because it is redundant.

```
    where leagueid = 2096 and 
              start_time >= 1415938900 and 
             ((matches.radiant_team_id= 1848158 and matches.dire_team_id= 15) 
                 or (matches.radiant_team_id= 15 and matches.dire_team_id= 1848158))
```

### Whole query

```
    SELECT 
    matches.radiant_name,
    matches.dire_name, 
    TA.Count as teamA,
    TB.Count as teamB, 
    TA.Count + TB.Count AS total_matches,
      (CASE 
            WHEN series_type = 0  THEN 1
        WHEN series_type = 1  THEN 2
          WHEN series_type = 2  THEN 3
      END) as wins_goal
    FROM matches
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT radiant_team_id, COUNT(id) AS Count
    FROM matches
```

*this part is redundant*

```
    WHERE leagueid = 2096 and 
              start_time >= 1415938900 and 
             ((matches.radiant_team_id= 1848158 and matches.dire_team_id= 15) 
                 or (matches.radiant_team_id= 15 and matches.dire_team_id= 1848158))
```

*this part is redundant*

```
    GROUP BY radiant_team_id) AS TA ON TA.radiant_team_id = matches.radiant_team_id
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT dire_team_id, COUNT(id) AS Count
             FROM matches
```

*this part is redundant*

```
    WHERE leagueid = 2096 and 
              start_time >= 1415938900 and 
             ((matches.radiant_team_id= 1848158 and matches.dire_team_id= 15) 
                 or (matches.radiant_team_id= 15 and matches.dire_team_id= 1848158))
```

*this part is redundant*

```
    GROUP BY dire_team_id) AS TB ON TB.dire_team_id = matches.radiant_team_id
```

*this part is redundant*

```
    WHERE leagueid = 2096 and 
              start_time >= 1415938900 and 
             ((matches.radiant_team_id= 1848158 and matches.dire_team_id= 15) 
                 or (matches.radiant_team_id= 15 and matches.dire_team_id= 1848158))
```

*this part is redundant*

```
    GROUP BY series_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well, you should be able to achieve it using temporary table as follows:

```
/* Create temporary table with the set of records that were the cause of query part redundancy */
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE      
    _tmp_matches
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    matches
WHERE leagueid = 2096 and 
      start_time >= 1415938900 and 
      ((matches.radiant_team_id= 1848158 and matches.dire_team_id= 15) 
         or (matches.radiant_team_id= 15 and matches.dire_team_id= 1848158));

/* Use the created temporary table */

SELECT 
    _tmp_matches.radiant_name,
    _tmp_matches.dire_name, 
    TA.Count as teamA,
    TB.Count as teamB, 
    TA.Count + TB.Count AS total_matches,
    (CASE 
        WHEN series_type = 0  THEN 1
        WHEN series_type = 1  THEN 2
        WHEN series_type = 2  THEN 3
    END) as wins_goal
FROM _tmp_matches
     LEFT JOIN 
     (  
        SELECT radiant_team_id, COUNT(id) AS Count
        FROM _tmp_matches
        GROUP BY radiant_team_id
    ) AS TA 
    ON TA.radiant_team_id = _tmp_matches.radiant_team_id
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT dire_team_id, COUNT(id) AS Count
        FROM _tmp_matches
        GROUP BY dire_team_id
    ) AS TB 
    ON TB.dire_team_id = _tmp_matches.radiant_team_id
GROUP BY 
    series_id;

/* Delete no longer needed temporary table */

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE _tmp_matches;
```

I hope it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I`m not so good in SQL, but you can try to store the redundant statement on a variable, and then call it whenever you need.

Comment: i did it but. im not comfortable with it. thanks for the answer.